# Starting the GUI terminal with specific variables

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm a relatively new user to Linux, so bear with me. I'm currently taking on the [Linux From Scratch project](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/), and I have reached a point where it calls for opening a new terminal with certain environment variables. The entire book is intended to be performed in command-line mode, which I am able to access with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> (or <kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd> or...), but primarily for comfort I prefer to use a terminal window.

The book, in chapter II, section 4.4, calls for the reader to create a `~/.bash_profile` with only one command: `exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=$TERM PS1='\u:\w\$ ' /bin/bash`, which "ensures that no unwanted and potentially hazardous environment variables from the host system leak into the build environment". I've added to the command a dummy variable `Q` to ensure that it is functioning properly.

When running Ubuntu in a virtual command line, the script is read as expected, and I have the new terminal with the variables initialized. However, I don't get this behavior if I open a terminal window through the GUI.

Is there any way to open a GNOME Terminal with specific environment variables like what is done by the above `exec` for the Linux console?

Comment: add the export into `~/.bashrc` and close and reopen the terminal window. and the corresponding `~/bash_profile`is called in ubuntu `~/.profile`

Comment: @Videonauth Hm. Why is it that when I have no `~/.bashrc`, `env` still outputs a lot of environment variables?

Comment: because of `/etc/bash.bashrc` file

Comment: @Videonauth is there a way to make the GNOME terminal for a *specific user* ignore `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: Yes, make a backup of your bashrc file in your home folder and make an empty one. an empty .profile aswell overrides the default

Comment: @Videonauth To be certain, you mean, create an empty `~/.bashrc`, and this will override `/etc/bash.bashrc`, correct? Because if you did, this was unsuccessful, as was creating an empty `~/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38713/discussion-between-videonauth-and-bhustus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is having `gnome-terminal` behave like a virtual console as far as rc scripts are concerned.

That should be achieved by configuring it to run the shell as a login one.

> Edit → Profile Preferences → Title and Command → Run command as login shell

Comment: Thanks much - This did exactly as I expected, once the new profile was set to be the profile opened with. However- the PS1 variable isn't getting set as expected either here or in virtual console mode. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: What does it look like ?

Comment: When I enter the terminal the PS1 variable is the standard. `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

Comment: Never mind, I managed to fix it by setting the variable in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Great. Looking to that file would have been my next suggestion.

Comment: All the same, it seems like `/etc/bash.bashrc` is being parsed, and it's inserting some variables I don't want...

Comment: Append `--norc` to the line exec'ing `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Will this also ignore `~/.bashrc`, or just `/etc/bash.bashrc`? Because a different part of the section calls for a user-defined `.bashrc`

Comment: It should ignore both.

Comment: Drat... is there any way to ignore only the `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

Comment: No, but you might conditionally source `~/.bashrc` from your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38750/discussion-between-bhustus-and-jlliagre).